# Highlighting Differential Pairs in Altium

Tags: altium, differential, pcb-fabrication

The PCB was designed, the gerbers were extracted in rs274x format. But it doesn't include the rs274-x2 version (so doesn't include differential pair impedance information). What can I do to highlight the differential pairs in Altium as below to show the manufacturer that some traces contain differential pairs?

[image]

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium forum:  https://live.altium.com/signin?prmGotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.live.altium.com%2F%23%2F

Comment: I am using the student version provided by the school. No access to the forum

Comment: *Valid* student licenses should have full access to the forum.  See: https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/student-license

Comment: For my designs with impedance controlled traces, we have a PCB drawing that has a table that gives the net name and impedance (and its reference).

Comment: Hey Smith thats good idea.Can gerber files contain net names(netlist)?If so, I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to highlight the differential pairs in Altium as below
> to show the manufacturer that some traces contain differential pairs?

Depends on which version you have, if you have a version that doesn't support draftsman, you are limited to doing the documentation yourself. You could exporting layers as a PDF and highlighting them yourself or screenshots layer by layer in a document editor.

If you do have draftsman you can click import board fabrication view and change the layer to whatever layer you want to document in the properties panel (properties panel -> layer) then use callouts to document which traces are which. You can also import the transmission line table. I do this for each layer so I have callouts for each layer. Then export as pdf